# Statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause error using trigger in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a trigger for auditing record insert,update and delete. My code is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[mytable_insertafter_audit]
ON [dbo].[mytable]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                            THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                            THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                            THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                        ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".   
                    END)

    IF (@Action = 'I')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO audit_trg
            SELECT 
                lr.sanction_status, i.sanction_status,
                GETDATE(), lr.id, 'mytable', @Action 
            FROM
                mytable lr
            INNER JOIN
                INSERTED i ON i.id = lr.id
    END
    ELSE IF (@Action = 'U')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO audit_trg
            SELECT
                i.sanction_status, lr.sanction_status,
                GETDATE(), lr.id, 'mytable', @Action 
            FROM
                mytable lr
            INNER JOIN 
                DELETED i ON i.id = lr.id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO audit_trg
            SELECT
                lr.sanction_status, i.sanction_status,
                GETDATE(), lr.id, 'mytable', @Action 
            FROM 
                mytable lr
            INNER JOIN
                DELETED i ON i.id = lr.id
    END
END
```

and audit_trg table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[audit_trg]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [old_status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [new_status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [u_datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ref_id] [int] NULL,
    [table_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [actions] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_audit_trg] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but I get error after some inserted that is

> The target table 'dbo.mytable' of the DML statement cannot have
>   any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause
>   without INTO clause.

Comment: Link statement which caused the error

Comment: Link statement means what?

Comment: You provided the code for the table and trigger. Please provide the code for the insert statement which caused that error to be thrown.

Comment: i don't know because i inserted large no.of rows at a time,it is difficult to identify.So any other option to find problem?

Comment: why it occurs? @Xedni

Comment: Whatever insert statement you have is attempting to use an OUTPUT clause to return data. However, as the error states, if the table has a trigger, the only way you can use an `OUTPUT` clause is if you put the results into a table (temporary or otherwise). It has to do this because if the trigger modified the data or rolled back the statement, the `OUTPUT` data would be false data. You're going to have to hunt through your code for statements using `OUTPUT` clauses for that table tracked by the trigger.

Comment: Side note: There might b a mistake in your trigger - in your case statement you set the value of `@Action` to I, U, D or NULL. But later on the code, you are treating NULL and D the same.

Comment: in which case @Action becomes NULL?@ Zohar Peled

Comment: in case both the inserted and the deleted tables are empty. It's in your code :-)